# Function to reverse the input string.Display the reversed string but just with pointer no brackets[],no libraries..function will change in memory

Tags: c, pointers, memory, reverse

```
int *i;

ters_cevir(){

    char *term=i;
    char *som=i;
    char som1;
    while (*term != '\0') { term++; }

    while (*som != '\0') {
        som1=som*;
        *term=som;
        term--;
        som++;
    }
}

int main() {   
    char *isim=malloc(sizeof(char)); 
    i=&isim;
    printf("Reverse words=");
    scanf("%s",isim);
    printf("Kelimenizin tersi:\n ");
    ters_cevir(); // When I call this, it must make the reverse one that make from memory
    while (*isim != '\0') {
        printf("%c",*isim);
        isim++;
        sayac++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have modified your code. Please see below also see my comments:-

```
void ters_cevir(char *isim){

    char *term=isim;
    //char *som=isim;
    //char som1;
    while (*isim != '\0') { isim++; }

    while (*term != '\0') {
        //som1=som*;
        *--isim=*term++//isim was pointing to the null character so we are pre decrement that pointer  and post decrement term
                    //here we are coping the string in reverse order in isim
        //term--;
        //som++;
    }
}

int main() {   
    char *isim=malloc(50);//you need enough space to store a string. you have just allocated only one byte which was not enough
    //i=&isim;
    printf("Reverse words=");
    scanf("%s",isim);
    printf("Kelimenizin tersi:\n ");
    ters_cevir(isim); // now it will work fine. Here you are passing the address of isim
    while (*isim != '\0') {
        printf("%c",*isim);
        isim++;
        sayac++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not compile because of syntax errors such as `som1=som*;`

You should pass the string as an argument to `ters_cevir();` instead of a global variable `i` with an incorrect type `int *`.

After fixing these problems, `ters_cevir()` will still not achieve the expected result because it overwrites the string from the end with characters from the start, with an off by one error.

You could correct this by swapping characters at `*som` and `*term`, but be careful to stop when `som >= term` otherwise you will reverse the string twice.

Futhermore, the code in `main` is completely broken.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *reverse(char *str) {
    char *term = str;
    char *som = str;
    char c;
    while (*term != '\0') { term++; }

    while (som < term) {
        term--;
        c = *som;
        *som = *term;
        *term = c;
        som++;
    }
    return str;
}

int main() {   
    char buf[128]; 

    printf("String to reverse: ");
    if (scanf("%127[^\n]", buf) == 1) {
        printf("Reversed string: %s\n", reverse(buf));
    }
    return 0;
}
```